# Syntax error with update statement

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Can some help me with this issue? I have seen many questions similar with this kind of issue but still i could not find the solution?

```
myConnection.Open()
            Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = myConnection.CreateCommand()
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Register SET [Name]=@Name, Email=@Email, Password=@Password, Mobile=@Mobile, Address=@Address, Blood=@Blood WHERE Name='Name'"
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            myConnection.Close()
            MsgBox("Your record update successfully !")
```

Comment: I have error in line "cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()"

Answer (score 0):

Your query is parameterized, but you didn't provide the required parameters.

For example:

```
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Register SET Email=@Email, Password=@Password, Mobile=@Mobile, Address=@Address, Blood=@Blood WHERE Name=@Name"
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.String).Value = NameTextBox.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.String).Value = EmailTextBox.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.String).Value = "XYZ" 'Must be hashed
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Mobile", SqlDbType.String).Value = "111-111-1111"
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Address", SqlDbType.String).Value = "100 King Street"
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Blood", SqlDbType.String).Value = "A+"
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Also the condition `WHERE Name='Name'` is strange. I believe it should be parameterized too, but it is still not a good practice to update the record by the name, you should use the ID instead.

Comment: Can u help with it?

Comment: i have tried and the message box popped out "record updated successfully" but the data in ms access database remains the same

Comment: That's probably because you don't have a record in the database with the `Name` column set to value 'Name'. You have to change your condition `WHERE Name='Name'` like I said. We don't see your data, so we cannot help you with that, but your query is now working.

Comment: myConnection.Open()
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = myConnection.CreateCommand()
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Register set Email='" + EmailTextBox.Text + "' WHERE Name='" + NameTextBox.Text + "'"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("Your details updated successfully!")
        Response.Redirect("User Login.aspx")
        myConnection.Close()....im using this code now....it works fine but only one field is updating...if i add one more set...it wont works

Comment: Don't use an inline query. The parameterized query in your question is much better. I edited my answer to include the `NameTextBox.Text` and `EmailTextBox.Text` values. Follow the same to add the other values.